# after logging in my 2nd action is not getting dispatch after login success action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

This is my auth.js action file where i have created loginUser and loadUser action. Inside loginUser action i have called loadUser() action. But the action loadUser is not being activated after LOGIN_SUCCESS action type.

```
export const loadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  if (localStorage.token) {
    setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
  }

  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/auth');

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_ERROR,
    });
  }
};

export const loginUser = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({
    email,
    password,
  });

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/auth', body, config);

    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    dispatch(loadUser())
  } catch (err) {
    const error = err.response.data.msg;

    if (error) {
      dispatch(setAlert(error, 'danger'));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAILED,
    });
  }
};
```

i tried so much to figure out the error but i dont know what is interfering with the action due to that only the first action is activated. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going to use it for the second action, then you don't need to export loadUser() method.

Just have it be a method in that file and then call it after the dispatch

```
 ...
 dispatch({
   type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
   payload: res.data,
 });

 loadUser();
 ...
```

Comment: Didn't worked. I created a page before dashboard. it had link to go to dashboard. After i log in then i go to that page. And when i only go to that page before going straight to dashboard the loadUser() action gets activated. But if i directly go to dashboard after logging in loadUser() action is not activated due to which user will be null and error pops up until i refresh the dashboard page.